# Internal server error 500 when working with API's

Tags: java, api, debugging

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but,

Today I was making a program using a popular game's API (Riot Games - League of Legends) and I was only making simple calls to do something like

```
import com.robrua.orianna.api.core.RiotAPI;
import com.robrua.orianna.type.core.summoner.MasteryPage;
import com.robrua.orianna.type.core.summoner.Summoner;
import com.robrua.orianna.type.core.common.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author William
 */
public class APIUtil 
{
    private Scanner scan;
    private Summoner summoner;

    public APIUtil()
    {
        RiotAPI.setAPIKey("b6121770-0eb0-4d59-9bfd-2a362b1d337b");
        RiotAPI.setRegion(Region.NA);
        RiotAPI.setMirror(Region.NA);
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        summoner = RiotAPI.getSummonerByName(scan.nextLine());
    }

    public void setSummoner(String summonerName)
    {
        this.summoner = RiotAPI.getSummonerByName(summonerName);
    }

    public Summoner getSummoner()
    {
        return this.summoner;
    }

    public void printMasteryPages()
    {
        List<MasteryPage> list = RiotAPI.getMasteryPages(summoner);
        for (MasteryPage page : list)
        {
            System.out.println(page);
        }  
    }  
}
```

now when i go to my main method in a seperate class and create an APIUtil object and call the printMasteryPages method, I get nothing but invalid 500's now in my output?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.robrua.orianna.type.exception.APIException: A INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500) error was received from the server for URI https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/mastery?api_key=b6121770-0eb0-4d59-9bfd-2a362b1d337b&masteryListData=all
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.dto.BaseRiotAPI.get(BaseRiotAPI.java:230)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.dto.BaseRiotAPI.get(BaseRiotAPI.java:163)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.dto.StaticDataAPI.getMasteries(StaticDataAPI.java:124)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.dto.BaseRiotAPI.getMasteries(BaseRiotAPI.java:402)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.StaticDataAPI.getMasteries(StaticDataAPI.java:332)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.StaticDataAPI.getMasteries(StaticDataAPI.java:374)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.RiotAPI.getMasteries(RiotAPI.java:565)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.SummonerAPI.getMasteryPagesByID(SummonerAPI.java:85)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.SummonerAPI.getMasteryPagesByID(SummonerAPI.java:97)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.SummonerAPI.getMasteryPagesByID(SummonerAPI.java:106)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.SummonerAPI.getMasteryPages(SummonerAPI.java:55)
    at com.robrua.orianna.api.core.RiotAPI.getMasteryPages(RiotAPI.java:610)
    at APIUtil.printMasteryPages(APIUtil.java:38)
    at APIDrv.main(APIDrv.java:14)
```

Just earlier today this was working. I'm not expecting anyone to be familiar with the API specifically but what causes internal 500's? as far as i have googled it is explicitly a server-side issue not client? meaning that their api is just down or something?

Any insight would be great,
Thanks!

Comment: It is a server-side thing. Your code should be fine, unless you're messing up a key or there's something on their API documentation that says when you might get 500 errors.

Comment: Yeah i intentionally messed up my key earlier to check, and i got a different error when that was the case. So i guess i just have to wait until it comes back online?

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is a server side error. You can enable additional output through the server settings (if you have access).

Comment: yeah i definitely do not, as its someone else's API that i'm using